# Group by and Join two tables via Linq and nested foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query:

```
var Linq6 = from c in northwindEntities.Categories
            join p in northwindEntities.Products on c.CategoryID equals p.CategoryID
            group c by c.CategoryName into Category                                
            select Category;

foreach (var item in Linq6)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    foreach (var i in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" {i.CategoryName}");
    }
}
```

But the above LINQ query gives me this output:

```
Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
 Beverages
Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
 Condiments
Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
 Confections
Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
 Dairy Products
Grains/Cereals
 Grains/Cereals
 Grains/Cereals
 Grains/Cereals
 Grains/Cereals
 Grains/Cereals
 Grains/Cereals
 Grains/Cereals
Meat/Poultry
 Meat/Poultry
 Meat/Poultry
 Meat/Poultry
 Meat/Poultry
 Meat/Poultry
 Meat/Poultry
Produce
 Produce
 Produce
 Produce
 Produce
 Produce
Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
 Seafood
```

Actually, what I want is the second foreach loop to print Product Name instead of category name which I can't find. Can some one help?

Comment: How about you `select` the `Product` instead of the `Category` ?

Comment: what do you mean? I need to category to show category name first.

Comment: @bit is right try this `Console.WriteLine($" {i.ProductName}")`  instead of `Console.WriteLine($" {i.CategoryName}")`

Comment: no. that won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first group by and then join the both collection like

```
var Linq6 = (from p in northwindEntities.Products
             group p by p.CategoryID into grp
             join c in northwindEntities.Categories on grp.Key equals c.CategoryID
             select new
             {
                 Key = c.CategoryName,
                 Products = grp.ToList()
             }).ToList();


foreach (var item in Linq6)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    foreach (var i in item.Products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" {i.ProductName}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: glad to hear, please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to do this:

```
from c in northwindEntities.Categories
        join p in northwindEntities.Products on c.CategoryID equals p.CategoryID
        group c by c.CategoryName into Category                                
        select new { CategoryName = Category.Key, Products = Category.ToList() };
```

Then you can iterate the name and the products

Comment: How to select the product name in the second foreach loop?